# ggplot prioritize line overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  select(ID, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  gather(key, value, 2:5) %>% 
  mutate(violation = c(rep(FALSE, 96), rep(TRUE, 32))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, value, group = key, color = violation)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_classic()
```

In the image below the red *'violation'* line is broken up into segments. I assume this is because `ggplot` is plotting lines sequentially, and one of the grey lines, is plotted after the red line, with the same coordinates. How do I stop the grey lines from overlapping the red?

As referenced in other stackoverflow questions, I would add a seperate line like this:

```
geom_line(df %>% filter(violation == TRUE), aes(color = "red")) +
```

but this causes problems when there are no violations in my data frames. I do monthly analyses and some months contain violations, some months do not. If I add this single line above I get an error *"must be length greater than 0"* for the months absent violations, so this one-liner approach probably won't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered  playing with the transparancy using `alpha`?

Comment: This is pretty much a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120088/ggplot2-bring-one-line-to-the-front-but-save-the-colors).  The top answer of adding `... + aes(group=rev(key))` will also work in this case.

Comment: @H1 I added your suggestion in the answer below. I hope that is ok with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the following code (with only 2 minor changes as compared to your code)

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  select(ID, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  gather(key, value, 2:5) %>% 
  mutate(violation = c(rep(FALSE, 96), rep(TRUE, 32))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, value, group = key, color = violation)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) + 
  geom_line(alpha = .5, size= 1.2) + ### changes in transparancy and thickness ###
  theme_classic()
```

Yielding this plot:
[image]

"H 1"'s suggestion is an alternative approach which changes the sequence of line drawings:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  select(ID, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  gather(key, value, 2:5) %>% 
  mutate(violation = c(rep(FALSE, 96), rep(TRUE, 32))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, value, group = key, color = violation)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = rev(key))) + ### changes sequence of plotting of the lines ###
  theme_classic()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]